# Format of lw/sw Operations in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am taking an architecture course currently and as part of that class I am learning MIPS assembly.

It is my understanding that the lw and sw operations are I-format instructions allowing 2 register operands, and one immediate operand:

```
[opcode] 6-bits, [rs] 5-bits, [rt] 5-bits, [immediate] 16-bits

    written as:
    lw  $rt, offset($rs)     # where offset is an immediate value
```

OK, so let's say I want to access A[i]. Assuming the base address of A is in register $s7 and the index (i) is in register $s1, I would have to do something along the lines of:

```
    sll $t0, $s1, 2      # i*4 (offset)
    add $t0, $s7, $t0    # $t0 = &A[i]
    lw  $t1, 0($t0)      # $t1 = A[i]
```

What I'm confused about is my professor keeps saying that we can also do a lw instruction like this with 3 registers:

```
    sll $t0, $s1, 2      # i*4 (offset)
    lw  $t1, $t0($s7)    # $t1 = A[i]
```

Are both of these solutions correct? Or is my instructor incorrect? You can't use a register for the offset can you? I thought the offset had to be an immediate number. It was my understanding that the reason you have to do the extra *add* instruction in the first solution, is actually because you *cannot* use a register as the offset.

Comment: assembly language as a language is defined by the assembler, the program that reads it and makes machine code out of it.  It is not generally (if ever) a standardized language like C++ or JAVA wit some committee somewhere.  MIPS already has commonly used pseudo instructions and this could be another pseudo instruction for some specific assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset for `lw`/`sw` must be an immediate. If your instructor claims that there's a variant of `lw`/`sw` in the MIPS instruction set that accepts register offsets then he/she is incorrect.

However, there might be assemblers that accept such a variant as a *pseudo-instruction*, and translates it into actual MIPS instructions. In this case, a possible translation might be:

```
addu $at,$s7,$t0
lw  $t1, 0($at)
```

Comment: To be pedantic, the (obsolete) MIPS DSP architecture extension included the `lwx $rd,$rxxx($ryyy)` instruction which allowed a register to be used as an offset.